# Render page from view via javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to render the page when i click on particular div.

For that i written div as:

```
<div id="idFlip" onclick="javascript:renderPages();">
-----------content---------------------
</div>
```

written javascript function as:

```
function renderPages() 
    {
        alert("Inside");

        @RenderPage("~/Views/PP/Teacher_Observation.cshtml");    
    }
```

But its showing me that page while the page itself is load.(i.e. showing me both views current one and Teacher_Observation.cshtml

Its not showing me on div click.

What can i do???

Please help me.

I want to render page on click of div through javascript function

Answer (score 1):

You could render the view on page load inside of a hidden div e.g:

```
<div id="idFlip">
     <div id="i-am-the-view" style="display:none">
          I am some hidden content
     </div>
</div>
```

And then in Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#idFlip').click(function(){
         $('#i-am-the-view').toggle(); 
    });
});
```